Why the google maps rotation controls doesn't work?
I have a problem when i try to implement the google maps api - rotation feature.
I followed the official Google documentation, but it doesn't work.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/webgl/webgl-tilt-rotation
This is the code with the map declaration:
        this.googleMaps = window.google.maps;

        this.map = new google.maps.Map(
            document.getElementById("map"),
            {
                zoom: 7,
                center: {lat: 45.9833801, lng: 24.8165617},
                heading: 320, //used for map rotation
                tilt: 47.5, //used for map rotation

                mapTypeId: 'hybrid',
                labels: true,

                //define which UI Controls to show
                disableDefaultUI:  true,
                zoomControl:       false,
                mapTypeControl:    false,
                scaleControl:      false,
                streetViewControl: false,
                rotateControl:     true,
                fullscreenControl: false,
                gestureHandling :  'greedy'
            }
        );

This is the code for control buttons
function setupControls() {
    const buttons = [
        ["Rotate Left", "rotate", 20,this.googleMaps.ControlPosition.LEFT_CENTER],
        ["Rotate Right", "rotate", -20, this.googleMaps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_CENTER],
        ["Tilt Down", "tilt", 20, this.googleMaps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER],
        ["Tilt Up", "tilt", -20, this.googleMaps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER],
    ];

    buttons.forEach(([text, mode, amount, position]) => {
        const controlDiv = document.createElement("div");
        const controlUI = document.createElement("button");

        controlUI.classList.add("ui-button");
        controlUI.classList.add("bg-white");
        controlUI.classList.add("text-base");

        controlUI.innerText = `${text}`;
        controlUI.addEventListener("click", () => {
            adjustMap(mode, amount);
        });

        controlDiv.appendChild(controlUI);
        this.map.controls[position].push(controlDiv);
    });

    const adjustMap = function (mode, amount) {
        switch (mode) {
            case "tilt":
                this.map.setTilt(this.map.getTilt() + amount);
                break;
            case "rotate":
                this.map.setHeading(this.map.getHeading() + amount);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    };
}

I do not receive any error in console.
Thanks!
I tried to implement google maps rotation and the control buttons doesn't works.
